# Angular2 Directive Child Selector Not Working?

Tags: css, angular, selector, directive

This question is originated when I had issue with this [conflicting circle tag](https://github.com/ng2-ui/ng2-map/issues/57)

When I define a directive like the following, I was expecting this directive only applies to `inner-tag` followed by `div` tag.

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'div > inner-tag'
})
export class InnerTagDirective {

  constructor() {
    alert('this is from InnerTagDirective');
  }
}
```

However, when I run the app with the following html

```
<div>
  <inner-tag></inner-tag>
</div>
<inner-tag></inner-tag>
```

It applies twice instead of once.

https://plnkr.co/edit/ToLutjTDg4908huLmY7B?p=preview

Is this angular2 bug, or am I misusing it?

-------- EDIT ------
For, someone who is curious on use cases, there are some cases.

```
<svg>
  <circle>  <!-- this should display SVG circle -->
</svg>

<ng2-map>
  <circle>  <!-- this should display google map circle -->
</ng2-map>
```

Comment: this seems like it could cause some confusion. i never even thought to try this!  why not just create a second directive with a unique tag for the `inner-tag` elements that are not within a div?